# Material Components Default to colorAccent instead of colorPrimary

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android, material-components

My `AppTheme` in `styles.xml` looks like this:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
    </style>
```

I set this in Manifest as:

```
<application
    android:name=".MyApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
```

According to https://material.io/develop/android/components/
The default color applied to my widgets should be the defined colorPrimary, but mine are picking up colorAccent as the default color. For example, this button:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="56dp"
        android:text="login"
        app:cornerRadius="5dp"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:fontFamily="@font/gotham_bold" />
```

[image: Observed behavior]

[image: Expected Behaviour]

Am I missing a specific config for this project for this to have button to show `colorPrimary` and not `colorAccent`?

Comment: Use the version 1.1.0 (currently -rc02)

Comment: This helped, thanks. I just updated to the latest material version suggested by the IDE, and the behavior corrected itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Material Components Library **1.1.0** or later.

The default style of the `MaterialButton` is:

```
    <style name="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="backgroundTint">@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector</item>
        <!-- .... -->
    </style>
```

**Starting from** the version **`1.1.0`** the `@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector` is based on the `?attr/colorPrimary`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorPrimary" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.12" android:color="?attr/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```

In the version [`1.0.0`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.0.0/lib/java/com/google/android/material/button/res/color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_selector.xml) the selector was based on `?attr/colorAccent`:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="?attr/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true"/>
  <item android:color="@color/mtrl_btn_bg_color_disabled"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

in this case i believe only the color of text in your button has changed, it has the color value of textColorPrimary.
There is a chance that textColorPrimary and colorAccent are the same

Comment: Hi, I may not have been clear. The attributes and values are set correctly. Only the background color was not behaving as expected. I expected the button background to be blue, as the `colorPrimay`, but it was yellow, as `colorAccent`

Answer (score 0):

First create `btn_style` in your `styles.xml` or `themes.xml`

```
<style name="btn_style" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button">
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
</style>
```

then in you layout apply the style and use the `color` or `drawable` that you want

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="@color/YOUR_COLOR"
            style="@style/btn_style"
            android:text="Test"/>
```